# .apply() method confusion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

am a newbie in JavaScript and was just learning how to use .call() and apply(). So far I learned that .apply() expects an array after giving it a "this" reference. So while playing with some code, I rn into this little problem whereby .call() works but .apply() does not even though am passing it an array. Can you please explain the problem to me. Thanks

```js
let obj = {
  arr: [2, 3, 4, 5],
  add: function(array) {
    return array.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  },
  multiply: function(array) {
    return array.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
  }
}

let answer = function(op, arr) {
  if (op == "add") {
    console.log(this.add(arr));
  } else if (op == "multiply") {
    console.log(this.multiply(arr));
  }
}.apply(obj, "multiply", obj.arr);
```

```
//Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object at main.js:17
```

Comment: `apply`'s second argument should be an array. `'multiply'` is a string, not an array.

Comment: This is a good question - I can't see what's immediately wrong with it.

Comment: Oh so all arguments after setting "this" should be arrays or does it only accept two arguments including setting "this"?

Comment: Hie again, I know my question is marked as a duplicate but the question you are pointing me to is super complicated, so, please reconsider, thanks

Comment: Only because a duplicate target is _complicated_ doesn't make it a non-duplicate. The important part in the dupe target is the last code-block (with `path` being a string and not an array). The problem is the same, the solution (as shown by Jonas in its answer here) is the same.

Comment: Ok thanks @Andreas, will ask better questions next time

Comment: _"...will ask better questions next time"_ - I haven't said anything about the quality of your question O.o

Answer (score 1):

Apply expects an array of arguments, just wrap the arguments in an array:

```
 .apply(obj, ["multiply", obj.arr])
```

---

[`Function.prototype.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

> The `apply()` method calls a function with a given this value, and **arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object)**.
>
> ---
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - `thisArg`
>     Optional. The value of `this` provided for the call to *`func`*. Note that `this` may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in [non-strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) code, [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) and [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.
> - `argsArray`
>     Optional. An array-like object, specifying the arguments with which *`func`* should be called, or [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) or [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) if no arguments should be provided to the function. Starting with ECMAScript 5 these arguments can be a generic array-like object instead of an array. See below for [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Browser_compatibility) information.
>     Return valueSection
>     The result of calling the function with the specified this value and arguments.
>
> **Return value**
>
> The result of calling the function with the specified `this` value and arguments.

Comment: This isn't particularly useful.

Comment: @dwjohnston feel free to edit this community wiki, or vote to reopen

Comment: Oh so all arguments after setting "this" should be arrays or does it only accept two arguments including setting "this"? @Jonas

Comment: @ofentse the second one, it only accepts two arguments.

Comment: Oh okay, I guess I thought that when they say it accepts arrays, it meant that the last argument must be an array. I continue to study up on it, much appreciated